# Passing function in the addListener event of the google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm building a javascript object Map to be able to treat events over a Google Map.

I want to be able to pass a function to be executed when the event occurs:

```
var MapMarker = (function ($) {

    bindClickEvent = function (marker, action) {

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', action);
    };

    return {

        bindClickEvent: bindClickEvent,
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
 var action = PartnerDetail.load(id);   <=== it gets executed here

 MapMarker.bindClickEvent(marker, action);
```

The issue is that it gets executed before the call and I want to be able to pass any function to be executed in the addListener event.

Answer (score 0):

Well. You already answered that. Pass the function action as a function object. It is important to know: when you execute the function and save it in a variable (action), action will no longer be a function it will be an object that whatever returned by the executed fn.

So for now define the action as

```
PartnerDetail.load
```

Comment: Hi thanks, and how you pass it? I tried it and it was executed in the call

Comment: You mean it worked but still want to pass 'id'? Or what exactly?

Comment: Yes How can I pass the id?

Comment: Ok there are two ways to do that but since its a google lib i wouldn't mess around much with it. Make sure to add a property to the PartnerDetail class where it is easy for you to access. Inside the class use { id : xx }, .. Access that by ClassName.id  another way: add .bind to the defined function but thats a bit of a headache as bind requires you to specify the 'this' keyword before passing 'id'. read more about bind before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a function literal with a closure...

```
MapMarker.bindClickEvent(marker, (function (i) {
        return function () {
            PartnerDetail.load(i)
        }
    })(id)
);
```

This creates a closure on the i parameter which is a reference to id.
The object passed to the event listener is a function that will load id when executed.

You don't need the action variable.

You could also hide that in your bindClickEvent object...

```
var MapMarker = (function ($) {

    bindClickEvent = function (marker, action, id) {

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(i){ 
            return function(){
                action(i)
            }
        })(id));
    };

    return {

        bindClickEvent: bindClickEvent,
    };

})(jQuery);

MapMarker.bindClickEvent(marker, PartnerDetail.load, id)
```